# How does web socket mode work if I deploy my Slack at two different stabilities/environments?

Tags: python-3.x, slack-api, slack-bolt

I have developed a Slack application using Python Bolt SDK. I was running in the WebSocket mode till now from my local machine for its development and now I need to deploy my Slack application to the Development environment/stability provided by my company which is restricted means I cannot have HTTP Public calls hitting my Slash command endpoints so I need to continue using the web socket mode to make it work when my application will be deployed to Development and later to QA and Production environment.
Now my question is, if I deploy my Slack application on the real development server provided by my company in the web socket then how will I run the same application on my local machine (for any ongoing local development) using the web socket mode only? How Slack will be intelligent enough to understand in making the judgment that there are few requests that it needs to route to the development server code and few to the local server code? I mean is there any way I can configure my app to continue doing my local development while my app is running on a different server using the web socket mode provided by Slack?